# Same Browser - Different Cipher

Tags: apache, ssl

I have an old Centos server that I need to migrate to a new server.

I believe I have the old and new system to be somewhat similar; both Apache and PHP and other configurations.

On the old system I see the following in the SSL logs

`AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`

On the new system I see the following in the SSL logs

`AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)`

I'm using the same browser (Firefox)

How is it that if I compiled Apache the same and am using the same version of SSL that the ciphers are different between two similar systems?

Comment: When you compiled your Apache, did you link to the systems' OpenSSL or one you compiled yourself?  Different OpenSSL == different results.  The most secure way is to get the latest OpenSSL and compile it yourself, unless you see that the one that comes with the system is the most recent.

Comment: thank you for your response; I did compile the same. on the old system I a config.status --config to pick up the parameters and reviewed the config.nice.